# Cypress testing for missing symbol in a font

Tags: css, font-awesome, cypress

We generate a custom font for icons in our website. Automatic icon usage detection has some problems to find all icons that are used on the website. I would like to add a Cypress test that renders our websites and detects if there are any content that has no symbols rendered.

Can I detect if content stated in css, like `content:"\f779"`, is rendered without a symbol showing by Cypress test framework?